# iOS: copying an object from oldArray to newArray

Tags: ios, replace, copy, nsmutablearray

I have oldArray that consists of many small arrays.
Now i want to take one of these objects (one small array), modify it, and then (if the user hits a button) replace it.
To do that:

Step 1 - I made a new array where I initialized newArray with that one small object.

```
openedCartProduct = nil;  
openedCartProduct = [NSMutableArray array]; 
[openedCartProduct addObjectsFromArray: [SharedAppDelegate.myEngine.shoppingCart objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Step 2 - Modify the array.

```
[[openedCartProduct objectAtIndex:0] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[inputRabatLabel.text floatValue]] forKey:kRABAT_KEY];
```

Step 3 - replace the object in oldArray.

In step 2, the modification is ALSO happening in oldArray even before replacing the object. Am i missing something here?

Thanks in advance guys! :)

**EDIT:**
The object modified is a small array consisting of a NSMutableDictionary at index 0 which I am modifying.

**EDIT**
Seems like we need a DEEP COPY here. I found a solution that is a but of a hack, but works fine, and is simple enough:

```
openedCartProduct = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[SharedAppDelegate.myEngine.shoppingCart objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
```

Comment: The second step makes no sense for an array. setObject:forKey: is an NSMutableDictionary method.

Comment: The object (small array) has two objects in it. The one at index 0 is a NSMutableDictionary where i am setting a specific value for one of its keys.

Comment: Try arrayWithArray instead of addObjectsFromArray.

Comment: Have tried with no luck. Still copying reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying a reference to the original small array. So that points to the small array in the first array when you change it.  That contains all the original contents.  If you want to alter it without changing it in the first array, you need to perform a copy, and in this case a deep copy, since it contains a mutableDictionary (that I assume you also want to copy).

Comment: That is correct. I understand that is what is happening. A deep copy where i have to set the values and keys manually?

Comment: In your simple case, you could just create a copy of the inner mutable dictionary before changing it.   I'm looking into my own code for how I've done a deep copy.  If I recall I used a kind of hack using JSONSerialization - but looking for a better answer for you

Comment: I have used the code below to deep copy.  But do better error checking (ommitted) `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arrayToCopy options:(NSJSONWritingOptions) 0 error:nil] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil]`

Comment: Thanks for the code above. I think I have found a solution that may or may not be GOOD. BUT it works and it is easy. See the edit above. What do you think?

Comment: That will work as long as your dictionary contains objects supporting the NSCoding protocol.   In other words - if it can contain instances of any of your own classes, you need to make sure they implement initWithCoder and encodeWithCoder.  But this takes care of the simple case.  But for that matter serialization won't work for classes without effort - so your solution works better

Comment: Yeah I can see what you are saying. Luckily it is a simple dictionary. Well, thanks! :) I will mark your answer correct since it pointed me in the right direction. And you got a couple of up votes :)